# CacheCallHandler Enterprise Library Contrib?

Tags: .net, asp.net, enterprise-library

The CachingCallHandler included in Enterprise Library 4.1 was removed for Enterprise Library 5.0+. The documentation refers to using the Enterprise Contrib Library to get this functionality, if needed.

My questions:

1. Where is this functionality in the Enterprise Contrib Library?
2. Does this work with Enterprise Library 5.0?

This is the only functionality I have a definite need for from Enterprise Library but may want to use the validation, as well. I don't see any reason to start with 4.1 when newer versions already exist. But, I'm slightly confused about where to find this functionality.

Of note, I don't see this method listed on their page.. still searching

Thanks

http://entlibcontrib.codeplex.com/
http://entlib.codeplex.com/

Edit:

I think this is the namespace, and I don't see the file in the latest download.

Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection.CallHandlers

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the

http://entlibcontrib.codeplex.com/

Source Code, EntLib 4.1, Click Download (upper right corner)

Comment: I still don't see the CachingCallHandler implementation for EL 5.0 in there.  I just see CachingCallHandlerAttribute.